# error Cannot read property 'split' of null in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I get this error in => Connecting To A Real API
" Cannot read property 'split' of null "
Please How fixed this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPES8.png

Comment: Can you add the output of the headers variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the header doesn't exist, it will (probably) return null. You then try to execute `split` on it, which fails and gives you the error.

try to first get the header and, if it is not not null, split it. otherwise it's 0.

Comment: OK Thank you ;)

Comment: A better example is in the code: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest/src/index.ts

if (!headers.has('content-range')) { ...